# Deleting cart items from session array in php

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have created a session array for items to go in a cart with its different properties. Each item has a remove button which deletes that item only.

FOR CREATING SESSION I HAVE USED

```
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $front = $_POST['front_select'];
    $back = $_POST['back_select'];
    $side = $_POST['side_select'];
    $oid = $_POST['orderID'];
    $pid = $_POST['pid'];
    $cart = array (
    'oid' => $oid,
    'front' => $front,
    'back' => $back,
    'pid' => $pid,
    'side' => $side

    );


    $_SESSION['cart'][] = $cart;

    print_r($_SESSION['cart']);
}
```

FOR DISPLAYING  ARRAY

```
 if(isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
                     $i = 0;
                        foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $item) {
                    if(isset($item['oid']) ){
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                            <?php echo $i;?>
                            <h5>ORDER ID : <b id="oid">#<?php echo   $item['oid'];  ?></b> | ORDER TYPE : <b id="product_type">BLOUSE</b> | PRODUCT ID :  <b id="product_id"><?php echo $item['pid']; ?></b></h5>
                            <hr>
                        </div>
 <a id="remove_btn" href="removefromcart.php?id=<?php echo $i; ?>" class="btn btn-danger waves-effect waves-light">Remove</a>

}
}
}
```

removefromcart.php PAGE

```
<?php

session_start();
if (isset($_GET['id'])){
$id = $_GET['id'];
unset($_SESSION['cart'][$id]);
    unset($cart[$id]);
$_SESSION["cart"] = array_values($_SESSION["cart"]);

header('Location: cart.php');

    echo $id ;
}
else
{
    echo "ID NOT FOUND";
}
?>
```

Whenever I click on remove button page refreshes due to header but nothing deleted.
What should I do Please HELP I really trust Stack overflow for helping noob coders.

AFTER THAT I USED below code to create array

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $front = $_POST['front_select'];
    $back = $_POST['back_select'];
    $side = $_POST['side_select'];
    $oid = $_POST['orderID'];
    $pid = $_POST['pid'];

    $cart = array (
    'oid' => $oid,
    'front' => $front,
    'back' => $back,
    'pid' => $pid,
    'side' => $side

    );

 $_SESSION['oid'] = $oid;
    $_SESSION['cart'][$oid] = $cart;

    print_r($_SESSION['cart']);
}
```

and getting

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [oid] => IT574deb7ddbfe3 [front] => IT1_front_6 [back] => IT1_back_2 [pid] => IT1 [side] => IT1_side_7 ) [IT574ded04c8af2] => Array ( [oid] => IT574ded04c8af2 [front] => IT1_front_6 [back] => IT1_back_3 [pid] => IT1 [side] => IT1_side_2 ) )
```

REMOVE BUTTON CODE

```
 <div class="row">
                                <a id="remove_btn" href="removefromcart.php?id=<?php echo $item['oid']; ?>" class="btn btn-danger waves-effect waves-light">Remove</a>
                            </div>
```

Array first key is 0 which creates a problem for me. In my cart first item always remains although its remove button url id has different id.

Comment: *In a nutshell...* => http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Sorry didn't get you

Comment: Your "FOR DISPLAYING ARRAY" code is improperly mixing PHP and HTML.

Comment: @PatrickQ: exactly why is that a problem? php is templating engine. If you want figure out how to output dynamic HTML without mixing in code, you could probabyl run the world, and don't say "use a template" engine, because that just turns it into "don't mix templating code with html", and you're back to square one.

Comment: @MarcB umm... what??  It's not the fact that OP is mixing the two, it's the way it's being done.  I'm assuming that the first 4 lines are already within an open `<?php` tag. OP then use HTML on line 5 without either closing the tag or using `echo`, `print`, etc.  Line 6 then opens another `<?php` tag when the previous one had not been closed.  So that's why exactly it's a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your delete isn't working, because you're not using that $id as your index when you build the cart:

```
$_SESSION['cart'][] = $cart;
                  ^--generate new ID based on current length of array
```

So if you have 3 items in your array, and add another one, its new index will be `3`, even if its $id happens to be 9999 or whatever.

You need to use that $id as the index everywhere:

```
$_SESSION['cart'][$id] = $cart;
                  ^^^---
```

and then your `unset()` will work as expected.

Comment: Please can you let me know how can I do so?

Comment: Hello Sir thanks for your answer it helps me a lot but i am getting array with its first value key as 0 rest as i defined I had updated my question please see.